# Can I stop a specific queue?

Tags: ibm-mq

Is it possible in IBM MQ through the console (command-line) to stop a queue?
I know how to stop a Queue Manager with `endmqm`. But can I run a console command which will stop one queue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop the queue"/"stop one queue"?  Do you want to prevent apps from putting to the queue or getting from the queue or both or something else?  Please edit your question and expand on what "stop the queue"/"stop one queue" means.

Comment: Agree with what @JoshMc says. A queue manager is a running entity, but a queue is not a running entity, so unsure what stopping it would mean. Applications are running entities that can make use of a queue, so one could imagine stopping a specific application that is making use of a queue.

Comment: @JoshMc, stop multiple queues or one queue. Or just put a ban on the entry and exit of messages

Comment: Do you want to prevent apps from putting to the queue or getting from the queue or both or something else? Please edit your question and expand on what "stop the queue"/"stop one queue" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A queue cannot be stopped independently of the queue manager.
However, you may find that restricting puts and/or gets on/from the queue achieves your desired goal, depending on your setup. This will allow you to prevent applications from adding new messages to the queue and/or removing messages from the queue.

This can be done using commands in the `runmqsc` interface. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_latest/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q083460_.htm

Here are the commands you'll need:

```
runmqsc QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME
ALTER QLOCAL('QUEUE_NAME') GET(DISABLED)
ALTER QLOCAL('QUEUE_NAME') PUT(DISABLED)
EXIT
```

Below is the commands and output for me disabling PUT and GET for my queue named Q1 on queue manager MyQM1.

```
mqa(mqcli)# runmqsc MyQM1
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2020.
Starting MQSC for queue manager MyQM1.


ALTER QLOCAL('Q1') GET(DISABLED)
     1 : ALTER QLOCAL('Q1') GET(DISABLED)
AMQ8008I: IBM MQ Appliance queue changed.
ALTER QLOCAL('Q1') PUT(DISABLED)
     2 : ALTER QLOCAL('Q1') PUT(DISABLED)
AMQ8008I: IBM MQ Appliance queue changed.
```

I'd recommend trying this out in a test environment first, to ensure it meets your needs and that your applications behave correctly to the error messages. E.g. "MQGET calls are currently inhibited for the queue. (2016)"